# Having problem applying one effect on other object in toonshading (Inverted Hull Outline)

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, shader-nodes, toon-shading

I'm new to this community.

I was trying to learn the toon shader method of rendering from a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/hBztmFHkNQo) by *tiptut*.

I'm having trouble copying a modifier from one object to another. I was using the method used to put the border on the object but, I could only apply it to the mushroom cap and not the mushroom stem. I tried copying the modifier and also tried the whole proceeds again for the stem but it doesn't help. how do I fix this?

The steps used:

- adding a new material to the stem object in the **material tab**
- adding **emission node** and connecting it to the **material output node(surface option)**
- selected the color used for the border and put it in the emission node.
- **added the solidify modifier** to the object. in the modifier , I set **material offset to 1** and **ticked the **flip**** normal option under **normals** setting.
- in the material I **ticked the backface culling** option in the material being used (mushroom border)
- after doing these steps I adjusted the thickness in the solidified material to get the desired border thickness.

I used these steps for putting the border on the mushroom cap but repeating the same won't work for the mushroom stem.

Can someone please guide me, on what am I doing wrong, or if there is an alternate way to get the same effect?

[image: the mentioned mushroom]

[image: the mentioned mushroom 2]

Comment: Have you checked the material index? The index starts at 0 for the first material. What does the stem look like when it's unselected (Alt+A)?

Comment: @Blunder I don't know how to check the material index or what it is, and the when de selected the stem looks exactly the same. the purplish border that you see on the cap ,its not visible on the stem.